# Move physics capsule at same acceleration regardless of surface slope

Tags: unity, physics

### Into:

I'm trying to move a capsule up/down a slope accelerating at the same rate as a capsule on a flat surface. I cannot set the velocity directly, because there will be many more forces affecting the capsule at the same time. So I'm using Unity's Constant Force component.

### Scenarios/Variables:

So for a **capsule on a flat surface**, I apply a ConstantForce of [-8,0] onto the body and it reaches the destination after 2 seconds from the moment the constant force was first applied. For this capsule variables affecting the capsule are:

```
Constant Force: [-8, 0]
Gravity: [0, -9.81]
Surface Angle (Normal): 0°
Time to Destination: 2s
Color: Blue
```

Now when I put the **capsule on an angled surface** moving UP the slope, the first step is to rotate the Constant Force unit vector to align with the Surface Angle. The second step is the compensate for gravity. Unfortunately I've had no success calculating this. Here are the variables I have:

```
Constant Force: [-5.7, 5.7]
Gravity: [0, -9.81]
Surface Angle (Normal): 45°
Time to Destination: > 2s
Color: Red
```

And for moving DOWN the same slope:

```
Constant Force: [5.7, -5.7]
Gravity: [0, -9.81]
Surface Angle (Normal): 45°
Time to Destination: < 2s
Color: Green
```

Here is a visual illustration of how the capsules are behaving under normal circumstances. For this, I'm just using the edge of the surface as the "destination" to measure the rate of acceleration. But it is very clear that neither of the capsules reach the edge of the surface around the same time.

[image]

So I then did another test and disabled gravity, where I concluded that I need to compensate for the forces coming from gravity.
[image]

### Assumptions:

At the moment I am assuming the gravity forces affecting the scenario are:

1. gravity onto the capsule itself
2. the collision/reaction force pushing the capsule away from the
   surface collider. Friction probably also involved?

### Question/TLDR:

How can I alter the Constant Force variable to compensate for gravity's affects onto the capsule?